# reshape unique strings in rows into columns in R

Tags: r, syntax, reshape, reshape2

I would like to reshape my data based in unique string in a "Bull" column (`all` data frame):

```
EBV       Bulls
0.13    NE001362
0.17    NE001361
0.05    NE001378
-0.12   NE001359
-0.14   NE001379
0.13    NE001380
-0.46   NE001379
-0.46   NE001359
-0.68   NE001394
0.28    NE001391
0.84    NE001394
-0.43   NE001393
-0.18   NE001707
```

My expected output:

```
NE001362    NE001361    NE001378    NE001359    NE001379    NE001380    NE001394    NE001391    NE001393    NE001707
  0.13        0.17        0.05       -0.12       -0.14        0.13       -0.68        0.28       -0.43       -0.18
                                     -0.46       -0.46                    0.84
```

I tried `dat2 <- dcast(all, EBV~variable, value.var = "Bulls")` but do not works.

Comment: You cannot have a function that returns sometime one output, sometime two. Do you want it to have as many columns as there are values of `EBV` per each occurrence of `Bulls`, or do you want the values of `EBV` to be in a list?

Comment: Some `EBV` occurrences in a different `Bulls` strings repeated more than anothers. That´s why I have more rows in some collumns than anothers. I would like just one collumn per `Bulls` occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options. Indexing the multiple occurrences for each level of `Bulls` or using a list to hold the different levels of `EBV`.

#### Option 1: Indexing multiple occurrences

You can use `data.table` to generate an index that numbers multiple occurrences of `EBV`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(all)                    ## convert to data.table
all[, index:=1:.N, by=Bulls]  ## generate index
dcast.data.table(all, formula=index ~ Bulls, value.var='EBV')
```

#### Option 2: Using a list to store multiple values

You could use a list as a value with `data.table` (I'm not sure if plain `data.frame` supports it).

```
require(data.table)
setDT(all)                       ## convert to data.table
all[, list(list(EBV)), by=Bulls] ## multiple values stored as list
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure that base R gets some acknowledgement:

```
## Add an ID, like ilir did, but with base R functions
mydf$ID <- with(mydf, ave(rep(1, nrow(mydf)), Bulls, FUN = seq_along))
```

Here's `reshape`:

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar="ID", timevar="Bulls")
#   ID EBV.NE001362 EBV.NE001361 EBV.NE001378 EBV.NE001359 EBV.NE001379
# 1  1         0.13         0.17         0.05        -0.12        -0.14
# 7  2           NA           NA           NA        -0.46        -0.46
#   EBV.NE001380 EBV.NE001394 EBV.NE001391 EBV.NE001393 EBV.NE001707
# 1         0.13        -0.68         0.28        -0.43        -0.18
# 7           NA         0.84           NA           NA           NA
```

And `xtabs`. Note: This is a table-like `matrix`, so if you want a `data.frame`, you'll have to use `as.data.frame.matrix` on the output.

```
xtabs(EBV ~ ID + Bulls, mydf)
#    Bulls
# ID  NE001359 NE001361 NE001362 NE001378 NE001379 NE001380 NE001391
#   1    -0.12     0.17     0.13     0.05    -0.14     0.13     0.28
#   2    -0.46     0.00     0.00     0.00    -0.46     0.00     0.00
#    Bulls
# ID  NE001393 NE001394 NE001707
#   1    -0.43    -0.68    -0.18
#   2     0.00     0.84     0.00
```